# Using os.environ to access environment variables?

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I'm trying to access the email address and email password of the current user environment but when I try to print the herein variables 'EMAIL_ADDRESS' and 'EMAIL_PASSWORD', I get None values.

I'm using an Android phone to code this simple project. Here is it:

```
import os
import smtplib

EMAIL_ADDRESS = 
os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')


subject = 'Practice email code'
body = 'This is my 1st output'
msg = f'Subject:{subject}\n{body}'



server = 
smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)




server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD, msg)
server.close()
```

Almost similar questions I've found here in StackOverflow have received a suggestion to make a new file containing the email ad and password. But is there a way to not cross with this solution? If none, what's the best you could recommend for a beginner to approach this problem? I don't have any much goal as I am yet to have a solid introductory skill. So as long as I could send the email through using the object 'os.environ' to access my email ad and password, I'm good to go.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Apparently those environment variables are unset.

Comment: Maybe you should just print the whole `os.environ` dictionary to see what is really set. I don't know much about Android, but if you are using anything like a `bash` shell to lauch your python script, then you may want to check whether you have `export`-ed the variables.

Answer (score 0):

That is not Python's problem. Try writing `bash` script to see if the two variables are really defined.